# Cyanogenmod not saving video + root missing

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, lg-g3

After rooting and flashing my LG G3 D855 with Cyanogenmod 12.1 I was quite satisfied, however I noticed that when I shoot a video from the rear camera the video would not save. The capturing would proceed normally but when you click on stop recording and look for the video in the gallery, it wouldn't be there.

What do I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the back video camera was set to record in 4K resolution.

The fix for the video camera issue is:

1. Go to the default camera app.
2. Swipe from the left to see the "Camera" "Video" Menu, on the bottom right corner the is a gear icon, press it to go to camera settings.
3. Go to resolution and quality and change the back camera video quality to 1080p instead of 4K.

For the root problem I found that you need to enable root once you have Cyanogenmod so you need to:

> Activate Developer options (settings->about phone, tap 'Build number' multiple >times).
>   In Developer options, tap 'Root access' and enable either "Apps" or "Apps and >ADB"

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/User:PsychoI3oy#Superuser_on_CyanogenMod_12.0

Comment: 1) Please enlighten how changing the resolution from 4K to 1080p is related to video not getting saved?

Comment: I have got no idea to be exact, but it worked.